# Ways to cancel downstream tasks in CompletableFuture chain when exception fired?

Tags: java, completable-future

My database methods return a CompletableFuture to do the work with database asynchronously and then process the result on the main thread.

```java
public interface IAccountDAO {
    CompletableFuture<ObjectId> create(AccountEntity accountEntity);
    CompletableFuture<Optional<AccountEntity>> get(String nickname);
    CompletableFuture<Void> update(AccountEntity accountEntity);
    CompletableFuture<Void> delete(AccountEntity accountEntity);
}
```

Each of the methods have following code inside (example of `get(String)` method):

```java
@Override
public CompletableFuture<Optional<AccountEntity>> get(String nickname) {
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
        try {
            // something logic
            return Optional.of(...);
        } catch (SomethingException ex) {
           ex.printStackTrace();
           throw new CompletionException(ex);
        }
    });
}
```

Handling the result:

```java
CompletableFuture<Optional<AccountEntity>> cf = get("Test_Nickname");

// Notify end user about exception during process
cf.exceptionally(ex -> {
    System.out.println("Database operation failed. Stacktrace:");
    ex.printStackTrace();
    return Optional.ofEmpty(); // I must return something fallback value that passes to downstream tasks.
});

// Downstream tasks that I would to cancel if exception fired
cf.thenAccept(...);
cf.thenRun(...);
cf.thenRun(...);
```

So, operation with database can fire exception. In this case I would to pass exception and using `.exceptionally(...)` or something like this notify the user called that method and **STOP** chain executing (cancel downstream tasks).

**My question is:** How I can cancel downstream tasks when CompletableFuture completed with exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can **cancel** the downstream tasks.

All you can do is just not execute the downstream tasks incase of exception.

```java
CompletableFuture<Optional<AccountEntity>> cf = get("Test_Nickname");

cf.whenComplete((response, exception) -> {
    if (exception == null) {
       // Downstream tasks that I would to like to run on this response
    } else {
       //Notify end user of the exception 
    }
});
```

To avoid nesting.

```java
private Response transformResponse(GetResponse r) {
   try {
          return SuccessResponse();
    } catch (Exception e) {
          return FailedResponse();
    }
}

get("Test_Nickname")
.thenApply(r -> transformResponse(r))
.thenCompose(... //update)
```

Comment: Really thank you for your response!
I would be grateful if you could answer one more question: Is CompletableFuture a good replacement for callbacks in my case?

I switched to CF in hope to get rid of nested callbacks, but in reality it turns out I don't get rid of nesting using CF?

For example: get(...) -> update(...).
It seems that I did not quite correctly understand the logic of the CompletableFuture's.

Comment: It really depends upon how you're coding. 

To avoid nesting of Callbacks, you can always transform your result into another response in case of any exceptions and then continue chaining.

Please find my updated answer.

Also, if it helped you please upvote.